# how to cache response from HTTP response?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

how to cache the response from HTTP request or cache response from interceptor in ionic 3 angular 4? and if data changed it automatically call API.

Comment: What did you try so far

Comment: im using interceptor for incoming and outgoing data , and observables in services

Comment: ``` algocombs(user: any): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + this.token  })
    };
    let url =this.config.baseURL+'/combination/systemCombination';
    let req = this.http.post<any>(url,user,httpOptions);
    return req.map((res)=>{return res}
        );
  }```

Comment: Do you use providers?

Comment: yes !!
```algocombs(user: any): Observable<any> {
 const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + this.token }) };
 let url =this.config.baseURL+'/combination/systemCombination';
 let req = this.http.post<any>(url,user,httpOptions);
 return req.map((res)=>{return res} );
 } ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if data changed it automatically call API.

this is not how a REST API works (assuming you're using REST).
You can cache request yourself by putting them in local storage or you can use a [standard plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-cache).
This way you still do the request but you first check if you have the data already locally. If this is the case the data will simply be pulled from local storage and the HTTP request will not be executed.

If you really want real-time updates you'll need a server-side way of letting your clients know that the data is changed but that is a whole different problem.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways, one is **IONIC Native HTTP**

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http

**Installation**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
npm install @ionic-native/http

import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

constructor(private myhttp: HTTP) {}


    this.myhttp.get('http://ionic.io', {}, {})
      .then(data => {

        console.log(data.status);
        console.log(data.data); // data received by server
        console.log(data.headers);
        ///here is response
      })
      .catch(error => {

        console.log(error.status);
        console.log(error.error); // error message as string
        console.log(error.headers);

      });
```

or you can use Angular **HTTPCLIENT**

https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: algocombs(user: any): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + this.token  })
    };
    let url =this.config.baseURL+'/combination/systemCombination';
    let req = this.http.post<any>(url,user,httpOptions);
    return req
        // .map((res)=>{ this.myData.next(res)}
       
        
        .map((res)=>{return res}
        );
      
        // this.obv=this.cache.loadFromObservable(url,req);
  }

Comment: there is no error basically I want to implement reusability of response without calling API again n again on the same page if response changes it automatically call API